# Ubuntu 21.10: Bluetooth headphones pair but PulseAudio doesn't discover it

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 21.10

I'm running ubuntu 21.04 on a framework laptop with an Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 wireless card. I downloaded the `iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz` driver from [here](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) and put it in `/lib/firmware`, so should be up-to-date. Also all my packages are up-to-date.

I want to listen to audio through my bluetooth headset instead of the laptop's built-in speakers. However, it doesn't seem to show up in `pavucontrol` no matter what I do, despite the headset successfully pairing. More details below.

My bluetooth device is successfully pairing:

```
$ bt-device -i 00:0E:DD:71:B0:6B
[00:0E:DD:71:B0:6B]
  Name: Shure AONIC TW2
  Alias: Shure AONIC TW2 [rw]
  Address: 00:0E:DD:71:B0:6B
  Icon: audio-card
  Class: 0x2c0404
  Paired: 1
  Trusted: 1 [rw]
  Blocked: 0 [rw]
  Connected: 0
  UUIDs: [00001100-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5, SerialPort, AudioSource, AudioSink, AVRemoteControlTarget, AVRemoteControl, Handsfree, 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 0000eb03-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5, 0000eb04-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5, 0000eb05-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5, 0000eb10-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5, 0000fd92-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
```

However, I can't get it to show up in `pavucontrol`:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
```

I have the module-bluetooth-discover and have tried:

```
$ pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
25
```

Here's the output of list-modules:

```
$ pacmd list-modules | grep -i bluetooth -B 1 -A 5
    index: 8
    name: <module-bluetooth-policy>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau, Pali Rohár"
        module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
        module.version = "15.0"
    index: 11
    name: <module-native-protocol-unix>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
--
    index: 25
    name: <module-bluetooth-discover>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "15.0"
    index: 26
    name: <module-bluez5-discover>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
--
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "15.0"
```

Here's what I find in dmesg:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    7.906019] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.906035] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.906037] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.906040] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.906042] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.914257] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2021.38 buildtype 1 build 31586
[    7.919323] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
[    7.919370] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[    7.919372] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 98-38.21
[    7.919373] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[    9.517963] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.517967] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.517971] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.558397] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.558402] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.558406] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

lspci:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01)
00:07.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 01)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 20)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b1 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN850 (rev 01)
aa:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Is it a bluetooth card in the machine or a USB device?

Comment: The Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 should support bluetooth, I believe

Comment: Did you do a complete shutdown and then boot?  Does this computer have another OS?

Comment: Yes to the first question, no it just boots Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm still trying to get the mic on my Shure TW2 working under Ubuntu, but no luck...

Comment: Same here, still trying to find a solution